# In django 1.11, how to allow users to login on a read-only database?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-1.11

I have 2 instances each running its own postgres database.

One is for production usage. The other is a read-only database that performs replication from the production database.

Both instances run the same django 1.11 application codebase.

When I attempt to login to the django read-only version, I cannot login because the very action of login apparently execute some update or insert statements.

I get an internal error about read-only database: `cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction`

What are my options if I want to allow users to access the read-only database using the same codebase?

### UPDATE

I have already tried `django-postgres-readonly`. Same results.

Comment: https://github.com/opbeat/django-postgres-readonly/blob/master/django_postgres_readonly/base.py ?

Comment: tried and same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the codebase that's talking to the read-only database

Step 1: install django-no-last-login v0.1.0

Step 2: inside settings.py add/change the following

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.file'

INSTALLED_APPS += [
    'nolastlogin',
]
NO_UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN = True
```

By default Django uses database for session engine, so switch to something else.

Also the plugin makes it easy to turn off the update last login behavior by Django.

Django auto updates the last login time. Since we want zero database writes, so we need to use that.

Answer (score 2):

Django need to update tables like `django_session`.

My advice is to use 2 different databases for the "django-tables" and your "read-only-tables"

How?

Create a simple and empty sqlite3 database and use the `class AuthRouter` 
for managed them.

For your database settings use something like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'otherdb': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'ypurusername',
        'PASSWORD': 'yourpassword',
        'HOST': '0.0.0.0'
    }
}
```

Example of AuthRouter:

```
class AuthRouter:
"""
A router to control all database operations on models in the
auth application.
"""
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to read auth models go to auth_db.
    """
    if model._meta.db_table == 'django-table':
        return 'defaul'
    return otherdb

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to write auth models go to auth_db.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
        return 'auth_db'
    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    """
    Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'auth_db'
    database.
    """
    if app_label == 'migrations':
        return db == 'default'
    return otherdb
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/) the link to the docs